# Why are all of my files in use by a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a Rails (5.0.5) app that manages image files. Users place files into a networked "dropbox" via a lab PC and then "claim" them through the app, which moves them into a separate, hidden storage directory.

I'd like to periodically delete files from this dropbox, but all 240+ of the images in the directory are "in use" and can't be deleted. They can be moved between directories on the network share but not deleted.

I thought it might have been a permissions issue on the mounted network drive, but `sudo lsof` shows:

```
ruby    26542 appuser  242r   REG   0,41   757370 32483 /mnt/filestore/dropbox/SCB EXAM.JPG
```

And `ps ax | grep 26542` shows:

```
26542 ?        Sl     0:02 Passenger RubyApp: /var/www/app/current (production)
```

To my knowledge, the app only accesses this dropbox directory to provide a list of its contents, to move single files into storage and to return files from storage. I can't reproduce the issue locally.

**What might keep these files "in use" by the app? Can I fix it so that I can delete files without stopping the server?**

If it helps, here is the code that lists images:

```
  def self.list_dropbox_images
    # returns array of hashes with keys "name" (only JPGs) and "time" (creation time)
    # File::FNM_CASEFOLD makes it case-insensitive. Nice.
    dropbox_dir.children.map { |child|
      if child.fnmatch?('*.jpg', File::FNM_CASEFOLD)
        { name: child.basename.to_s, time: File.new(child).ctime }
      end
    }.compact
  end
```

and the code that moves files from the dropbox to storage:

```
  def self.move_claimed_image(image)
    FileUtils.move(
      Rails.configuration.dropbox_dir.join(image.original_filename),
      Rails.configuration.storage_dir.join(membership_dir(image.course, image.user), "#{image.id}.jpg")
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `File.new(child)`, you are opening the `child` file in Ruby. The open File object (and with it the actual OS file handle) will stick around until the object is eventually garbage collected, which might be a long time depending on memory pressure. Until then, the file is still opened.

To fix this, you can get the file's ctime directly without opening the file first by using [`File.ctime` class method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-ctime) instead:

```
File.ctime(child)
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple fix